# Always returning false as boolean value

Tags: java, android

After user selecting area, there is a function called `checkCoverageGuest()`. This function checks whether selected area by the user is under coverage for that restaurantor not. If the restaurant is under coverage, then `checkCoverageGuest()` will return true value. When there is no coverage for that restaurant, `checkCoverageGuest()` will return false.

If the value is true then, it proceed to the next level which is checkout. If the value is false, the screen will display toast error message that the selected restaurant is not under coverage.

Right now, every this coming out from this function `checkCoverageGuest()` as false.

Here is my code.

```
private boolean checkCoverageGuest() {
    try {
        String url;
        if (appPrefs.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("ar"))
            url = LinksConstants.TEST_SERVER_URL
                    + LinksConstants.SEARCH_COVERAGE_AREA;
        else
            url = LinksConstants.TEST_SERVER_URL
                    + LinksConstants.SEARCH_COVERAGE_AREA;

        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
        city_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("area", city_id);

        NetworkRestClient.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                progressActivity.showLoading();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                progressActivity.showContent();
                JSONObject[] restaurants_arr = null;

                hasCoverageGuest = true;
                try {
                    if (response != null) {

                        JSONArray restaurants = response.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                        // if restaurants deliver to that area
                        if (!restaurants.getString(0).equals("null")) {
                            restaurants_arr = new JSONObject[restaurants.length()];

                            int has_coverage = 1; // assume coverage is there..

                            for (int j = 0; j < Utils.cart_restaurants.size(); j++) {
                                RestaurantModel restaurant = Utils.cart_restaurants.get(j);
                                String restaurantCartID = restaurant.getId();

                                boolean found = false;
                                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                                    restaurants_arr[i] = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String restaurantID = restaurants_arr[i].get("restaurant_id").toString();

                                    if (restaurantCartID.equals(restaurantID)) {
                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }  //end of inner for
                                if (found == false) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "There is no coverage for the Selected Area ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    hasCoverageGuest = false;
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            //end of outer for
                        } //end of if

                        else //if restaurants don't deliver to that area
                        {
                            hasCoverageGuest = false;
                        }

                    } // end of if response != null


                } // end of try

                catch (Exception ex) {
                    GSLogger.e(ex);
                    showError();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String errorResponse, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, errorResponse, throwable);

                showError();

                if (AppConstants.DEBUG_MODE)
                    showToast(errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

                showError();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
        showError();
    }
    return hasCoverageGuest;
}
```

Comment: Your method will return the default value of the variable, as the value will not be changed until later when the asynchronous method completes. You will need to call your logic from the callback, or wait for the async method to complete by using another variable.

Comment: @MattClark How can I achieve that? Can you help ? I am pretty new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `private boolean checkCoverageGuest()` method returns before `public void onSuccess()` is executed, this is the reason for `checkCoverageGuest()` always returning false.

If you need to execute something after you get the `hasCoverageGuest` good value then excute it inside `onSucess()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a callback to specify success or failure. one way to do that is using interface.

```
public interface notifyGuestCoverage {
      void hasCoverage(int status);
}
```

in onSuccess,

```
if (!restaurants.getString(0).equals("null")) {
     notifyGuestCoverageObj.hasCoverage(true);
}
```

This interface will be implemented by class which requires value of has coverage. for ex,

```
class Example implements notifyGuestCoverage{
    void hasCoverage(int status){
            //your code
    }
}
```